# Correlation computation of non 0 elements

Tags: r

Frame that looks like this:

```
Col1     Col2    Col3     
 0        3      25     
 45       0      0
 0        0      12
```

I would like to compute correlation index between elements only if the two elements are != from 0 because 0 in my case is "not informative item" so it does not make sense to compute a correlation between for ex: 3 that is informative and 0 that is not informative.

I cannot remove the columns containing 0 elements simply because 0 elements are sparse in my data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One half of what you are looking for is `use = "pairwise.complete.obs"` in `cor`:

> If `use` has the value "pairwise.complete.obs" then the correlation or
>   covariance between each pair of variables is computed using all
>   complete pairs of observations on those variables.

However, it requires to have `NA` values instead of zeros, so let us transform our data first:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 0, -1, 0, 1),
                 y = c(-1, 0, 1, -1, 0),
                 z = c(0, 0, 1, -1, -1))
data
#    x  y  z
# 1  1 -1  0
# 2  0  0  0
# 3 -1  1  1
# 4  0 -1 -1
# 5  1  0 -1

tempData <- data
tempData[tempData == 0] <- NA
tempData
#    x  y  z
# 1  1 -1 NA
# 2 NA NA NA
# 3 -1  1  1
# 4 NA -1 -1
# 5  1 NA -1
```

Finally:

```
cor(tempData, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
#    x  y  z
# x  1 -1 -1
# y -1  1  1
# z -1  1  1
```